# How to combine Prestashop (PHP) and DjangoCMS (Python)

Tags: php, python, django, apache, prestashop

I need to use DjangoCMS and prestashop with the same url, for example :

`localhost/shop = prestashop<br>
localhost/everythingElse = DjangoCMS<br>`

my prestashop is installed in `/var/www/prestashop` and djangoCMS is installed in `/var/www/djangoCMS`.

Linux Mint 14 64 bits, apache2, mod_python, wsgi...

I've tried this conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/djangoCMS"
ServerName localhost
WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/djangoCMS/djangoCMS/apache/django.wsgi"
<Directory "/var/www/djangoCMS/djangoCMS/apache">
    Options +ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/prestashop"
ServerName php.localhost
<Directory "/var/www/prestashop">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Django works fine on localhost but I can't access to php.localhost : Oops! Google Chrome could not find php.localhost

Comment: probably `php.localhost` isn't resolved properly. You either need to add an entry in your `/etc/hotsts` file or if you're using a dns server configuer it to resolve it properly, and properly set up a `NameVirtualHost` directive in your apache config.

Comment: Thanks you ;) I use django on port 8000 (./manage runserver 8000) and I've added php.localhost on /etc/hosts. Now I have to remove :8000 from url. Thanks again for your help. Have a nice day.

Comment: Runserver is only a development server, which is not suitable for production. If you want to remove :8000 from the URL just don't use Runserver, and use Apache instead.

Comment: I've seen sites built like this and it never comes across well. Either you're duplicating lots of the same interactions in two different languages or you have two sites that function and work differently.

Answer (score 1):

ServerName php.localhost means that you are telling Apache to answer any requests made to http://php.localhost For that you will need to add php.localhost to point to the server IP address (127.0.0.1 if it's your local dev environment)

This won't work in production envirioments. What I suggest is to use ProxyPass, where you can tell apache to redirect all calls to a specific port. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:9090>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/prestashop
    <Directory "/var/www/prestashop">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/djangoCMS"
    ServerName localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/djangoCMS/djangoCMS/apache/django.wsgi"
    <Directory "/var/www/djangoCMS/djangoCMS/apache">
        Options +ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass /shop http://localhost:9090
    ProxyPassReverse /shop http://localhost:9090
</virtualHost>
```

That way you will have prestashop running in port 9090, django in port 80 AND tell Apache to redirect all calls from http://localhost/shop  to http://localhost:9090